TypeError: 'coroutine' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol in pytest_asyncio
I am trying to preform asynchronous testing for a class who perform HTTPS request using aiohttp.ClientSession.
The issue I am having is that when I call  async with session.get as response the fallowing exception is raising

TypeError: 'coroutine' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol.

Here is my code:
class URLFetcher:
    def __init__(self, proxies=None, user_agents=None, rate_limit=1, cache=None, authentication: Authentication = None, session_manager=None):
        self.proxies = proxies or []
        self.user_agents = user_agents or [self.default_user_agent()]
        self.rate_limiter = RateLimiter(rate_limit)
        self.authentication = authentication
        self.session_manager = session_manager or SessionManager()
        self.cache = cache

    async def fetch(self, url, retries=3):
        cache = await self._pre_flight(url)
        if cache:
            return cache

        try:
            async with self.session_manager as session:
                async with session.get(
                    url,
                    headers=self.headers,
                    proxy=self.proxy,
                    timeout=10
                ) as response:
                    response.raise_for_status()
                    content = await response.text()

                    if self.cache:
                        self.cache.set(url, content)

                    return content
        except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
            logger.error(f"HTTP error for URL {url}: {e}")
            if retries > 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(2 ** (3 - retries))
                return await self.fetch(url, retries - 1)
            else:
                raise e

Here is the test:
@pytest_asyncio.fixture
async def url_fetcher():
    fetcher = URLFetcher()
    yield fetcher
    await fetcher.session_manager.close()


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_fetch_success(url_fetcher):
    # Mock the response
    mock_response = AsyncMock()
    mock_response.status = 200
    mock_response.text.return_value = 'Mock Content'

    # Mock the session.get methods
    mock_get = AsyncMock(return_value=mock_response)

    # Patch the ClientSession.get method
    with patch('aiohttp.ClientSession.get', new=mock_get):
        content = await url_fetcher.fetch('http://example.com')

        assert content == 'Mock Content'
        mock_get.assert_called_once_with(
            'http://example.com',
            headers=url_fetcher.headers,
            proxy=url_fetcher.proxy,
            timeout=10
        )

I am trying to mock async testing for my class.

Try patching aiohttp.ClientSession._request, aiohttp.ClientSession.get is a async context manager that wraps aiohttp.ClientSession._request, so by patching it with simple coro you are breaking context manager logic

thanks that work, but now for some reason the assert_called_once_with is failing with " AssertionError: expected call not found." I get the mock_response content and when looking at the mock get object properties I see it called once but still it fails.

When patching objects that use context managers, wrap the mock with contextlib.nullcontext.
import contextlib
from unittest import mock

import pytest


@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_aiohttp_client():
    mock_session = mock.Mock(
        spec=aiohttp.ClientSession,
        **{'get.return_value': contextlib.nullcontext(mock.Mock())}
    )

    with mock.patch(
            target='aiohttp.ClientSession',
            return_value=contextlib.nullcontext(mock_session)
    ):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            url = 'https://example.com'
            async with session.get(url=url):
                mock_session.get.assert_called_once_with(url=url)

